# How can I pass my Firebase database coordinates to onMapReady?

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I have latitude and longitude stored in my Firebase database as shown below (note the values aren't encased in ""):

```
Latitude: 53.868728
Longitude: -2.941631
```

I am trying to retrieve these values and pass them to .position() to update my mapView. I know that my Firebase paths are correct because my other queries for retrieving data are working. I also know that the map functionality works because if I pass coordinates directly to .position(), the correct location appears. Below is my onMapReady code for which the app crashes and there is nothing useful in the logcat:

```
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mapView = googleMap;

    final Double[] latitude = new Double[1];
    final Double[] longitude = new Double[1];
    coordinatesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Timetable/" + schoolID);
    coordinatesDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            latitude[0] = dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(Double.class);
            longitude[0] = dataSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(Double.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    LatLng schoolLocation = new LatLng(latitude[0], longitude[0]);
    mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(schoolLocation).title("School"));
        mapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(schoolLocation, 15.0f));
}
```

Here are the red lines for Run:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kitchen, PID: 23731
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.kitchen.SchoolProfile.onMapReady(SchoolProfile.java:378)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzak.zza(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:12)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source:12)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:675)
        at cj.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19831067@19.8.31 (100408-0):14)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bb.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19831067@19.8.31 (100408-0):4)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bi.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@19831067@19.8.31 (100408-0):2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)  
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Comment: *"the app crashes and there is nothing useful in the logcat"* - that's highly unlikely to be true.  There is at least going to be a stack trace with some indication of what line of code caused the crash.  Please edit the question to show this stack trace, and how you interpret it (tell us the line of code it refers to).

Comment: @DougStevenson Locat attached. I assumed there was nothing useful because only the first 2 lines are red.

Comment: There's no stack trace in there. Are you sure your app is actually "crashing"?  If it crashes in the way that most developers use that word, there will be a stack trace, or at least some indication of what went wrong. What exactly is going on?

Comment: @DougStevenson Ah sorry - I added extra info which does look to be a lot more helpful.

Comment: And which line is that error referring to? That's where your error is. You are trying to do something with a Double value but actually working with a null value.

Comment: I've initialised the variables, and then querying Firebase to assign values to those variables. I've done a toast to check the values are coming through and they are so I'm not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the results of the query before they're actually available.  Realtime Database queries are asynchronous, and the call to `addValueEventListener` returns immediately, before the query is compelte.  This means that `latitude` and `longitude` are going to contain null values at the time they're being used to populate the map.  You should move the code to deal with the map into the callback, which is the first time the values will be available.

```
        coordinatesDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                latitude[0] = dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                longitude[0] = dataSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(Double.class);

                // POPULATE THE MAP HERE WITH THE VALUES JUST READ

            }
```